# What's the difference between WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy and WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy()?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, proxy

I am wondering what the main differences are between `DefaultWebProxy` and `GetSystemWebProxy()`. There're some descriptions on MSDN, but I still feel I need a bit more details to have a better understanding.

Also, let's say I have following options for proxy configuration on my C# winform application

1. Auto-detect proxy settings
2. Use system default settings
3. No proxy

Then which method goes to which option? Is it right to say that `Auto-detect proxy` somewhat equals `Use system default` settings?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Per the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.defaultwebproxy.aspx) for `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy`, this property will provide the proxy information specified in the `app.config` file. It looks like the [.NET Framework v3.5 MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.defaultwebproxy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is missing this specific detail.

As far as `WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy()` goes, the [MSDN article for it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getsystemwebproxy.aspx) states that this method will provide the system-wide configured proxy (Control Panel > Internet Options).

---

This is how I would suggest you implement the three options outlined:

1. **Auto-detect proxy settings**

   - Implement your own proxy discovery logic; **or**
   - Change the system setting to match your application's setting, and use `WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy()` (*I wouldn't recommend this approach*); **or**
   - Preferably not include this option, and let the user use the corresponding system-wide setting along with the "Use system default settings" option;
2. **Use system default settings**

   - Use `WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy()`;
3. **No proxy**

   - Ensure to unset the `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy` and the `WebRequest.Proxy` properties;

---

**Edit:** If no proxy is configured in *app.config* `WebRequest.DefaultWebRequest` is *almost* the same as `WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy()` (at least for .NET 4.5). The difference is that `WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy()` will run the PAC script (if any) for proxy definition.
<sub>Thanks to [Gabrielius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14887679/whats-the-difference-between-webrequest-defaultwebproxy-and-webrequest-getsyste/14888220#comment50423799_14888220) and to [23W](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14887679/whats-the-difference-between-webrequest-defaultwebproxy-and-webrequest-getsyste/14888220#comment85555676_14888220) for the comments below.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Jesse. I will think about the ways to implement. Let's see what others have to say.

Comment: @woodykiddy you're welcome, however, can you elaborate some more on what you are trying to accomplish? Additionally, can you define the details you wish to clear up relating to the differences between `DefaultWebProxy` and `GetSystemWebProxy()`?

Comment: I am trying to provide options where user can choose whether to use proxy or not. The client application will apply proxy settings before calling the web service. As I said in my post earlier, I am just feeling a bit iffy here. It seems to me that these two APIs pretty much offer the same thing.

Comment: @woodykiddy they provide similar things, but not identical. `DefaultWebProxy` would be a setting in the app.config file - whether manually typed in by a user, or through application settings; and `GetSystemWebProxy()` is strictly the system-wide Internet Options setting. Basically, `DefaultWebProxy` can be used as your application's "custom proxy configuration", and `GetSystemWebProxy()` would equate to "use system settings".

Comment: It's several years passed already, but @Jesse, you may add a note that `WebRequest.DefaultWebRequest` is equal to `WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy()` initially, if no proxy is configured in _app.config_ (at least for .NET 4.5).

Comment: When "Use system default settings" uses PAC script for proxy definition `WebRequest.DefaultWebRequest` is NOT equal to `WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy()`. Even on .NET 4.5.

Comment: what if i set my proxy in the system(Computer's internet option Lan settings) and i want to bypass that proxy while using webclient ? any solution for it ?

Comment: GetSystemWebProxy() will not return the system-wide Internet Options settings on an new account that has never logged into any machine.  Just an FYI.